# About tap gesture in uiscrollview

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

I have an imageview in my scrollview,and i add a tap gesture for my uiscrollview.
[image]

only the imageview area can respond tap gesture.

why when i set the backgroudcolor property of scrollview，then the whole scrollview can respond tap gesture。

here is my code。

```
UIImageView * imgview=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bizhi1.png"]];    
imgview.frame=CGRectMake(0, 140, 320, 200);    

UIScrollView * scrollview=[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
[scrollview addSubview:imgview];

//when i set the backgroudcolor,then the whole scrollview can respond tap gesture
//scrollview.layer.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor].CGColor;

//add a TapGesture for scrollview
UITapGestureRecognizer * tapGesture=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(SwitchTabBarHidden)];    
[scrollview addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
[tapGesture release];

[imgview release];
[self.view addSubview:scrollview];
[scrollview release];
```

Comment: You wanna gesture on only both image view ?

Comment: just want the whole uiscrollview area can respond the tap gesture.

Comment: please get touch location coordinate - (void)singleTapGestureCaptured:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture

Comment: you sure that you  will get  toouch in scrollview or not ?

Comment: This code is working proper at my end. I think you are doing something wrong in other code.

Comment: @Deepesh  when i set the backgroudcolor of uiscrollview,i can get touch in any area in uiscrollview.

Comment: @DharmbirChoudhary that's so strange，i do this test is a new uiviewcontoller file, without any code but this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure this code is correct because i've implemented this code and there is no need to set the `backgroundColor` property of scrollview.

Comment: OK,i intend to create a new project for this test.

Comment: What happend my dear have you got it ?

Comment: that's true, there is no need to set the backgroudcolor property.   but i really create a new uiviewcontroller to do this, i think something else affect this. i will check it. thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure userInteractionEnabled is set to YES on the UIImageView:

```
frame.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Comment: hi! Rushabh. even i add imgview.userInteractionEnabled=YES;,it still only the imageview area can respond the tap gesture.